# Using Oracle Object Storage as a persistent Volume in Oracle Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to use **Oracle Object Storage** as a persistent Volume in **Oracle Kubernetes Engine**.

I have created a Kubernetes cluster and created a public bucket named `test-bucket`.

My yaml files are:

**storage-class.yaml**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: object-storage
provisioner: oci.oraclecloud.com/object-storage
parameters:
  compartment-id: 
  bucket-name: test-bucket
  access-key: 
  secret-key:
```

**pvc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: object-storage-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: object-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

**pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: object-storage-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: object-storage-container
    image: busybox
    command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: object-storage
      mountPath: /home/user/data
  volumes:
  - name: object-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: object-storage-pvc
```

I have applied all of the files but I am receiving this error when I create the PVC.

```
Normal  ExternalProvisioning  3m2s (x26 over 8m53s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "oci.oraclecloud.com/object-storage" or manually created by system administrator
```

I also tried to create the volume by myself but that also didn't work.

I have tried many different things but I am not sure If I am missing anything here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that would work, as using object storage as a PVC is currently not supported by OCI.

Here's an alternative that would work, but currently involves manual steps:

Install s3fs on each of your nodes. This will allow you to mount s3 bucket (including OCI's S3) as a mount folder. Then you can mount the volume into your container, using host path. If you restart your nodes, you will need to remmount the bucket, or setup a service to startup on reboot. If you have multiple nodes, or constantly delete/add nodes, it could be a pain.